# Sending Email via Spring Boot_Basic. Greeting Null Pointer Exception

Tags: spring-boot, nullpointerexception

I have created two classes EmailSenderService.java and SpringEmailDemoApplication.java as below.

EmailSenderService.java

```java
@Service
public class EmailSenderService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    
    public void sendEmail(String toEmail,
                          String subject,
                          String body){
    
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom("ABC@gmail.com");
        message.setTo(toEmail);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);
    
        mailSender.send(message);
    
        System.out.println("Mail send via Spring Boot Successfully...");
    
    }
}
```

SpringEmailDemoApplication.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringEmailDemoApplication {
    @Autowired
    public EmailSenderService senderService1;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringEmailDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void sendMail(){
        senderService1.sendEmail("XYZ@gmail.com",
                "Spring boot Email sender",
                "Hi How are you.");
    }
}
```

But I am getting null pointer exception after running the program when calling `senderService1.sendEmail`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sumitcodes.SpringEmailDemo.SpringEmailDemoApplication.sendMail(SpringEmailDemoApplication.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:344) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing I would ask is have your configured your JavaMailSender?

Next, have you tried running in a your IDE debugger ?
Start with a breakpoint on the sendEmail call in your sendMail() method.  Then step through the code and you should get closer to the cause.

Comment: Original question needs more detail.   Is this the only code written? Assuming its a Spring project?  How is it setup? How is the mailSender configured?  Unable to comment directly on the original question.